In matlab simulink how can I use an inport as a coefficient in a transfer function?
I have a fairly simple transfer function to model in matlab. It's this:
K_in/(M*s+1), where M is a defined variable and K_in is an inport.
In simulink it looks like this:
K_in -----> Tranfer fcn: 1/(M*s+1) -----> K_out
I don't see how to modify the numerator coefficient to K_in. (I can modify coefficients, just can't see that inport as an option to use there.)
I'm new to Matlab so probably I'm missing something simple.
